# How to display the subpackages of a package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some third party library called `a` and from code examples I learned it has a subpackage `b1`, i.e.,

```
from a import b1
```

Is it possible to see all the subpackages of `a`? Package `a` is not pure python and it is not obvious from the file structure to tell the subpackages. I tried `dir` but it only shows attributes of `a`

```
import a
dir(a)
```

Comment: Is this an open source library? If so, can you share a link?

Comment: unfortunately it's a commercial one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the package author provided an explict index of the package modules, then the convention is to define a list named [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) that contains this index. So you could do something like the following to see all the submodules / subpackages of an imported package (example prints all json submodules as determined by the package author):

```
import json

subs = json.__all__
print(subs)

# OUTPUT
# ['dump', 'dumps', 'load', 'loads', 'JSONDecoder', 'JSONDecodeError', 'JSONEncoder']
```

If the package author did not provide an index of the package modules, then it will be much more difficult to sort it out. One approach would be to use `dir` and then sort or filter the attributes by type in an effort to narrow down to a set likely to be submodules / subpackages. Here is an example that might be useful.

```
import json

def sort_by_type(t):
    return t[0].__name__

attrs = [(type(getattr(json, attr)), attr) for attr in dir(json)]
attrs.sort(key=sort_by_type)
for t, n in attrs:
    print(t, n)

# OUTPUT
# <class 'json.decoder.JSONDecoder'> _default_decoder
# <class 'json.encoder.JSONEncoder'> _default_encoder
# <class '_frozen_importlib.ModuleSpec'> __spec__
# <class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'> __loader__
# <class 'dict'> __builtins__
# <class 'function'> detect_encoding
# <class 'function'> dump
# <class 'function'> dumps
# <class 'function'> load
# <class 'function'> loads
# <class 'list'> __all__
# <class 'list'> __path__
# <class 'module'> codecs
# <class 'module'> decoder
# <class 'module'> encoder
# <class 'module'> scanner
# <class 'str'> __author__
# <class 'str'> __cached__
# <class 'str'> __doc__
# <class 'str'> __file__
# <class 'str'> __name__
# <class 'str'> __package__
# <class 'str'> __version__
# <class 'type'> JSONDecodeError
# <class 'type'> JSONDecoder
# <class 'type'> JSONEncoder
```

Comment: unfortunately that package doesn't have `__all__` defined

Comment: @nos - in that case, it will be fairly tricky. Edited the answer with an approach that may be helpful to get you started with the investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `__all__` if available to list all the possible items that the python package contains.

Try the following code:

```
for i in sklearn.__all__:   
   try:
      y = eval('sklearn.{}'.format(i))
      for j in y.__all__:
      if 'package you want to find' in j.lower():
         print(i,' - ',j)   
   except:
     pass
```

Comment: I get those errors only but no output not even w/o the if clause:
exceptions  -  NotFittedError
exceptions  -  ConvergenceWarning
exceptions  -  DataConversionWarning
exceptions  -  DataDimensionalityWarning
exceptions  -  EfficiencyWarning
exceptions  -  FitFailedWarning
exceptions  -  SkipTestWarning
exceptions  -  UndefinedMetricWarning
exceptions  -  PositiveSpectrumWarning